# What does fixed and dynamic causal structure mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, time, causality

In the following articles: [Hardy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0509120.pdf) or [Qvarfort](https://sofiaqvarfort.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Indefinite-Causal-Structures.pdf). It is said that Newtonian an Quantum mechanics present a **finite causal structure** while General Relativity and QFT presents a **dynamic causal structure**.

The difference between the two is that:

- **Fixed**: The physicist must choose which causal order corresponds to the system he wants to model and the corresponding equations results from this choice.
- **Dynamic**: The causal order emerges directly from the problem considered.

My problem is that I don't understand the examples given to understand which theory corresponds  to which causal structure. Do you have any simple examples to understand?

In the second paper, an explanation given to explain why Newtonian mechanics have a fixed causal structure is that for an elastic collision between two objects, Newton’s 2nd
Law doesn't say whether the acceleration causally precedes the force or the opposite. Which is an argument that I don't understand.

Comment: This terminology is not standard, and definitely questionable. Google 'dynamic causal structure' and you will only get papers by Hardy. I don't get the point either, but the first paragraph of chapter 2 in the Hardy paper you cite makes it clear that his intended goal is to find a general combination of quantum operators usable when no context is given about their time ordering - not too sure about the validity of the rationale here though, as it is not obvious to me why you would want to consider a spacetime event as equivalent to a quantum operator. I did not read further - just my 2 cents.